# Sudden additional scroll bar for wx.grid.Grid

Tags: grid, wxpython, scrollbar, wxwidgets

I use wx.grid.Grid for display table.
The number of grid rows is changed and it may be more than 2000.

For number of rows less than 1723 GUI displays normally.

But if I have greater than or equal to 1723 rows, GUI displays incorrectly:

- Sudden additional vertical scroll bar appears.
- If aim a mouse cursor on this additional scrollbar then my laptop display blinks
- wx.grid.Grid don't expands into ScrolledPanel.

**How can I use wx.grid.Grid with greate number of rows (more than 2000)?**

Thanks in advance.

Code Sample:

```
import wx
import wx.grid
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel

class TestPanel(ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, size=(640, 480))
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self._create_table(), 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetupScrolling()
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)

    def _create_table(self):
        _table = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1)
        _table.CreateGrid(0, 1)
        for i in xrange(1723):  # Work normally If I use 1722 rows
            _table.AppendRows()
            _table.SetCellValue(i, 0, str(i))
        return _table

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                title="Scroll table", size=(640, 480))
        self.fSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.fSizer.Add(TestPanel(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.fSizer)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use a `wx.Panel` instead of the `ScrolledPanel`.  The grid is able to manage its scrolling on its own, it doesn't need to have any help from its parent.

If you have other widgets to display that wont fit in the panel, and you want to be able to scroll them and the grid in and out of view, then using the `ScrolledPanel` would be appropriate, but then you should do something to constrain the size of the grid so it doesn't try to expand to show all cells.